# How is this a memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, fastmm

FastMM reports this line as the source of a memory leak :

```delphi
StrClassName := MidStr (curLine, length(START_OF_CLASSNAME)+1, length(curline)+1)
```

What's up with `Copy` and `MidStr`? Is this only a Delphi 2007 compiler bug, or do the later versions also have this problem? 
Here is the [link](http://pastebin.com/QL2Qx21r) to the copy of the FastMM report, and an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgy72.jpg) of how my applications displays those kinds of reports. See, in order to display the nodes in `VirtualTreeView` I need a new data type. I call it TMemoryLeak. When I parse the report, I give my `TMemoryLeak` a class name, the callstack, it's size etc. But when the app shuts down, and FastMM kicks in, the copy line from above seems to leak memory. I deallocate the callstack the size, the whole object, but the ClassName field which is a string always leeks memory.

**Update (from comment)**

Here are the declarations and constructors and deconstructors. As for the lifetime- the objects' deconstructors are called as soon as the objects are used to display the node tree, After that they are obsolete, and are deallocated (I hope).

```
TMemoryLeak = class(TObject)
    private
      fID              :integer;
      fSize            :integer;
      fTotalSize       :integer;
      fCallStack       :TStringList;
      fClassName       :string;
      fRepeatedInstance:integer;


    public
      property ID               :integer      read fID                write fID;
      property TotalSize        :Integer      read fTotalSize         write fTotalSize;
      property Size             :integer      read fSize              write fSize;
      property CallStack        :TStringList  read fCallStack         write fCallStack;
      property ClassName        :string       read fClassName         write fClassName;
      property RepeatedInstance :integer      read fRepeatedInstance  write fRepeatedInstance;
      class function Equal(xA: TMemoryLeak; xB: TMemoryLeak): Boolean;
      procedure clear;
      constructor create;
      destructor destroy; override;
  end;

  TMemoryLeakList=class(TObjectList)
    private
      fSortType         :TMlSortType;
      fSortDirection    :TMLSortDirection;
      fTotalLeakSize    :integer;
      fClassName        :string;
      fRepeatedInstance :Integer;
      fID               :Integer;
      function  GetItem(Index: Integer): TMemoryLeak;
      procedure SetItem(Index: Integer; const Value: TMemoryLeak);

    public
      property Items[Index: Integer]:TMemoryLeak      read GetItem             write SetItem; default;
      property TotalLeakSize        :integer          read fTotalLeakSize      write fTotalLeakSize;
      property SortType             :TMLSortType      read fSortType           write fSortType;
      property SortDirection        :TMLSortDirection read fSortDirection      write fSortDirection;
      property ClassName            :string           read fClassName          write fClassName;
      property RepeatedInstance     :integer          read fRepeatedInstance   write fRepeatedInstance;
      property ID                   :Integer          read fID                 write fID;

      function Add(AObject: TMemoryLeak): Integer;
      procedure Clear();
      procedure Sort;

      constructor create;
      destructor destroy; override;
  end;


constructor TMemoryLeak.create;
  begin
    inherited;
    fCallStack := TStringList.create;
    fRepeatedInstance:=0;
  end;
  destructor TMemoryLeak.destroy;
  begin
    clear;
  end;
  procedure TMemoryLeak.clear;
  begin
    fCallStack.Clear;
  end;
  class function TMemoryLeak.Equal(xA, xB: TMemoryLeak): Boolean;
  var i:Integer;
  begin
    Result:=False;

    if xA.ClassName = xb.ClassName then
    begin
      if xA.size = xb.size then
      begin
        if xA.CallStack.Count = xB.CallStack.Count then
        begin
          for i := 0 to xa.CallStack.Count - 1 do
          begin
            if CompareStr(xA.CallStack[i], xB.CallStack[i]) <> 0 then
            begin
             break;
            end;
          end;
          if i = xa.CallStack.Count then
            Result:=True;
        end
      end
    end

  end;

  { TMemoryLeakList }

  constructor TMemoryLeakList.create;
  begin
    inherited;
    fSortType         :=stID;
    fSortDirection    :=sdAsc;
    fClassName        :='';
    fRepeatedInstance :=0;
  end;
  destructor TMemoryLeakList.destroy;
  begin
    Clear;
  end;
  procedure TMemoryLeakList.Clear;
  var i : Integer;
  begin
      for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
        Items[i].clear;
  end;
```

Comment: Please show a full program that reports a leak.

Comment: where is the variable defined ?

Comment: coming right up in the edit.

Comment: @opc0de The variable is local in the procedure which parses the report. It's not the variable, it's the `AnsiString` which is used in the `Copy`/`MidStr` methods that leak memory.

Comment: Does this happen with variables you are watching in a debugger window? Or does this also happen when running outside the IDE?

Comment: Good point @Uli. Delphi IDE has a known flaw that debugger evaluator tooltips can result in leaks in your app!

Comment: This happens to me regularly with my D2007.

Comment: @UliGerhardt I noticed it the other day in XE2 but don't recall seeing it ever in XE3. Am I too optimistic to hope that it might finally have been fixed?!

Comment: @UliGerhardt no debugger involved. It happens without outside the IDE too.

Comment: Your `Equal` function is wrong, and the compiler should have warned you about it. You cannot read `i` after the loop has terminated normally. You can fix this easily by replacing `break` with `exit`, and then removing the final conditional statement so that you set `Result := True` unconditionally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The explanation that makes sense is that you have a memory leak.

I think you have a mis-understanding of how FastMM leak reporting works. You seem to infer from the leak report that `Copy`, `MidStr` etc. are responsible for the leak. That's not the case. A leak is reported when memory is allocated but not subsequently deallocated. In the case of functions like `Copy` and `MidStr`, their job is to create new strings which naturally involves allocation of memory. The leak is reported because the memory that was created to hold the string buffer was not deallocated. It is not the fault of `Copy` or `MidStr`, the allocating function, when the rest of the code fails to deallocate that memory.

Delphi 2007 is a mature product and the memory management for strings is known to be correct. Perhaps you do some manual memory copying that bypasses the reference counting for strings. Are you setting some variables/fields to `nil` with a call to `FillChar`? Are you disposing of a record with `FreeMem` instead of `Dispose`? The former will not decrement the strings reference count. Something like this is the likely cause of the leak.

---

Looking at extracts of the code you posted, this is a problem:

```
destructor TMemoryLeakList.destroy;
begin
  Clear;
end;
```

You have failed to call the inherited destructor. Which means that the members of the list won't be destroyed. Which explains why your string is not destroyed.

In fact you don't need to provide a destructor for the list class. Simply remove it and let the inherited `TObjectList` destructor do the work. Since `OwnsObjects`defaults to `True`, any members of the list are destroyed as soon as they are removed from the list, and when the list itself is destroyed.

If your `Clear` method actually cleared the list, then that would happen. But your `Clear` isn't a real `Clear`. A real `Clear` in a container is expected to remove all members. You should remove your `Clear` and rely on the inherited version.

In `TMemoryLeak`, you also fail to call the inherited destructor. And also fail to destroy the string list instance that is owned by that class.

To summarise, I'd write these constructors and destructors like this:

```
constructor TMemoryLeak.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  fCallStack := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TMemoryLeak.Destroy;
begin
  fCallStack.Free;
  inherited;
end;

constructor TMemoryLeakList.Create;
begin
  inherited;//by default OwnsObjects is set to True, list manages member lifetime
  fSortType :=stID;
  fSortDirection :=sdAsc;
end;
```

And then remove the `destructor`, and remove the `Clear` method. The versions inherited from `TObjectList` suffice.

In the comments you state:

> The objects' destructors are called as soon as the objects are used to display the node tree. After that they are obsolete, and are deallocated (I hope).

I'd say there's a good chance that this is not helping. Since you created the object list in `OwnsObjects` mode, you should not be destroying the members of the list at all. You've asked the list itself to do that. You can't both do it. And the "I hope" comment doesn't fill me with much confidence that this code is correct.

Since we can't see all of your code, I'm far from sure that this is the entirety of the problems with it.

The bottom line is that your code has leaks. Trust in FastMM!

Comment: True, but the callstack given by FastMM suggests no other culprit other than the those tho procedures, hidden in the `system.pas` file. I'll make a small example and copy it here. If you have FastMM, you'll be able to see for yourself :)

Comment: FastMM does not suggest they are the culprit. Merely that those functions allocated the memory. The failure is that your program fails to deallocate. FastMM does not attempt to work out why your program has not deallocated. It cannot do so.

Comment: You are thinking about this in terms of "why was this memory allocated here?" But that's the wrong perspective. Instead think "why is this memory not subsequently deallocated?"

Comment: In no scenario should `String1 := String2` be considered a memory leak, which is what FastMM IS telling me. If you know a way to explicitly deallocate a string, please let me know.

Comment: If you do everything right, string buffers are deallocated automatically. But since we can't see your program, we can't tell what's happening.

Comment: Manually freeing the string if the wrong solution, Goran. Instead, figure out why the string isn't getting freed automatically like strings are supposed to. Is there any place where you assign to a string via type-casting? Pass a string as an untyped parameter? You still haven't shown the rest of the function for this code.

Comment: I don't think it'll help, but here's the [code](http://pastebin.com/QtxkpWL2) to the procedure that traverses a `TStringList` (created by parsing through a .txt) and creates a list of lists of `TMemoryLeaks`. I can't paste the entire code unfortunately.

Comment: No, I don't think that helps. Perhaps the declaration of `TMemoryLeak` and `TMemoryLeakList` would help. Together with their constructors and destructors, and the code that manages item lifetime in `TMemoryLeakList`. But if I were you I'd start cutting the code down to a more manageable size, for the purpose of debugging this issue.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/fdMREZcj) are the declarations and constructors and deconstructors. As for the lifetime- the objects' deconstructors are called as soon as the objects are used to display the node tree, After that they are obsolete, and are deallocated (I hope).

Comment: @Goran_Mandic, I added code and above comment to your question, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Same error in `TMemoryLeakList.Destroy`. No `Inherited` call.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/fdMREZcj) are the declarations and constructors and deconstructors. As for the lifetime- the objects' deconstructors are called as soon as the objects are used to display the node tree, After that they are obsolete, and are deallocated (I hope). @David Heffernan, gotta go now, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Goran_Mandic I'm done here. I'm sure you've got a leak. I've picked apart the code that you have shown. It's not for me to work through your entire code base.